# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

The Workplace's [sixth moderator election](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/6) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: Mister Positive]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking jmort who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/6), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5371078903857152/0).

Comment: Well done Mister Positive!

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Thank you jmort253 for many years of service going back to beta!

Comment: Congratulations MisterPositive. May you be a great moderator for this site.

Comment: Congratulations and welcome to the team @MisterPositive.

Comment: Thanks @MonicaCellio.  Congratulations to the new moderator MisterPositive.

Answer (score 14):

Congratulations @MisterPositive ! Wish you the best on your role as Mod.

Comment: And congratulations to you on a strong second-place finish!

Comment: Thanks Monica. I'm looking forward to continue helping and contributing to this wonderful site :)

Answer (score 7):

Congratulations! I'm sure you'll uphold the strong tradition that The Workplace moderators have.

Answer (score 6):

Congratulations, TWP is in good hands

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations I'm sure you'll do fine.